# How to scrape a webpage lacking tags using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data from this page: http://www.kitco.com/texten/texten.html

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.kitco.com/texten/texten.html"
r = requests.get(url)

# Doing this to force UFT-8 encoding.  Not sure if this is needed...
r.encoding = "UTF-8"

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
tag = soup.find_all("London Fix")
print tag
```

As you'll notice while viewing the source of that page, the term "London Fix" is not in any tags - I'm not sure if this is cdata or what...

Any idea how to parse these tables??

Comment: Setting `r.encoding` is indeed not needed if all you are using is `r.content`. Which, incidentally, is perfectly correct.

Comment: I'm closing this as too broad, but I could also justify 'unclear what you are asking', because you have not specified what output you expected.

Comment: I suggest you start reading the [BeautifulSoup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) a little more carefully to see what `soup.find_all()` *does*, as well.

Comment: Last but not least, why not parse the HTML version at http://www.kitco.com/market/ instead?

Comment: Since the "London Fix" table is not actually a HTML table, the best you can do with this URL is get the `<font>` tag and then do a `next_sibling` on it, to get the entire table

Comment: @MartijnPieters, The main reason for using this URL was weight, as the page you referenced is rather heavy with ads, extra data, etc..  I was mainly just curious *if* BeautifulSoup would be able to parse the individual elements in those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @shaktimaan pointed in comments, the "London Fix" table is not a real one - it is inside the `pre` tag, rows are formatted using dashes.

One option would be to find the `font` tag before the table and get the [`.next_sibling`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.kitco.com/texten/texten.html"
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
print soup.body.pre.find('font', size="4").next_sibling.strip()
```

prints:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
London Fix          GOLD          SILVER       PLATINUM           PALLADIUM
                AM       PM                  AM       PM         AM       PM
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aug 29,2014   1285.75   1285.75   19.4700   1424.00   1424.00   895.00   NA  
Aug 28,2014   1288.00   1292.00   19.7500   1425.00   1428.00   897.00   898.00  
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

---

Another option would be to search by [`text`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-text-argument) (produces the same output):

```
import re

print soup.body.pre.find(text=re.compile('London Fix'))
```